# how to add vertical line between two forms using html and css

Tags: html, css

add vertical line between two forms and when screen size small it show horizontal line between forms [image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your current relevant code.

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/pe1yb1ye/

Comment: @RobertMoore without using flexbox property only using css can you please convert this jsfiddle code to simple css

Answer (score -1):

I answer just ans it as general please upload your code for more approx answer 
Use Border property & media query in css to attain it

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {border-right:black solid 2px; }

@media (max-width: 700px) {border-bottom:black solid 2px;}
```